# How to make buttons to not be a part of the window OnClick?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I click on the button, the function window onClick is called. I want the button function to be called first followed by the window. How do I make the function to be called in sequence?

```
window.onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "∠CAD=∠DAE (AD bisects ∠CAE)";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Select one of the statements to continue:";
  document.getElementById("button1").className = 'button1';
  document.getElementById("button2").className = 'button2';

window.onclick = myFunction2;
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Now let’s complete the proof! Select the next statement:";
        document.getElementById("button3").className = 'button3';
  document.getElementById("button4").className = 'button4';
}

 window.onclick = myFunction3;
function myFunction3() {
    $("#button3").animate({
//    top: $("#demo3").parent().width() / 2,
top: "-250",
    left:"+600"
}, 2000);

}     
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#button1").fadeOut();
    $("#button2").fadeOut();
    $("#demo2").fadeOut();
    $("#demo3").fadeIn();
  });

  $("#button3").click(function(){
      $("#tick").fadeIn();
      $("#button4").attr('disabled','disabled');


  });

  $("#button4").click(function(){
      $("#cross").fadeIn();
      $("#speech").fadeIn();
  });

});
```

Comment: You have 3 different functions assigned to `window.onclick` but only the last one will be called. Is that what you intended to do? And can you let us know why you need these `window.onclick`?

Comment: I want the function window onClick to be called in sequence. [myFunction, myFunction2, myFunction3]. I am not sure how to call it in order.

Comment: Need the window onClick function as I want the user to click on the screen to see the next step.

Comment: You are reassigning `window.onclick` 3 times, line by line which means only the last assignment is count for your code (it's as if you only write the last one)

Comment: you can wrap the three functions into a big function like `function main(){ function1(); function2(); function3(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Not minding your incorrect way of using  `window.onClick` and just focusing on the the main problem make other button not be part of the `window.onClick`.
`window.onClick` get all event of click on the page so why not just put a condition on your `window.onClick`.

```js
window.onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction(event) {
  var btn = event.target.className;
  if (btn == "not-part") {
    console.log("this will not trigger the other part of the function");
  } else {
    // Your other codes here
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="part">CLICK ME</button>
<button class="not-part">DON'T CLICK ME</button>
```